# how to get /?pollid=test inserted into my url with having to type it into the url everytime.... new to php

Tags: php

I am really struggling with how I get /?pollid=test inserted into my url when the page loads. Right now I have to type it and then the feature will work. /?pollid=test is calling the column and values from my sql table. can i hard code it in?

```
<?php

        $pollid = $_GET['pollid'];
        $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','poll');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM polls WHERE pollid = '$pollid'";

        $q = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
            $id = $row[0];
            $title = $row[1];
            $pollid = $row[2];
            $ipaddress = $row[3];
            echo "<h1>$title</h1>";
      ?>


        <table>
            <form action="" method="POST">
    <?php

        $questions = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE pollid = '$pollid'";
        $q2 = mysqli_query($connect, $questions);

        while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($q2)){
            $question = $r[1];
            $votes = $r[2];
            $newvotes = $votes +1;
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $newipaddress = $ipaddress."$ip,";


                if (isset($_POST['vote'])) {
                    $polloption = $_POST['polloption'];
                    if ($polloption == "") {
                        die("You did select an option.");
                    } else {

                        $ipaddresse = explode(",", $ipaddress);
                        if (in_array($ip, $ipaddresse)) {
                            die("You have already Voted");
                        }else{
                        mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE questions SET 
votes='$newvotes' WHERE pollid='$pollid' AND question='$polloption'");
                        //store ip address of the user so can only vote once
                        mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE polls SET 
ipaddress='$newipaddress' WHERE pollid ='$pollid'");

                                die("You votes successfully!");
                        }
                    }
                }

            echo '<tr><td>'.$question.'</td><td><input type="radio" 
 name="polloption" value="'.$question.'" />'.$votes.'votes</td></tr>';
                }

            }
    ?>

            <tr><td><input type="submit" name="vote" value="Vote"/></td></tr>
                </from>
            </table>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: `$pollid = "test"`

Comment: You also want to protect your database, so read [how to use prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @thebluefox thanks for the idea but this didn't work... I am trying to grab from the database a column of info with this $_GET statement. but unsure how to code that without inserting /?pollid=test in the url.

Comment: @C0dekid will check it out thanks

Comment: So `pollid` could be anything? It's not fixed to `test`?

Comment: use apache `mod_rewrite`

Comment: figured it out just added test to the query string, thanks for all the help $query = "SELECT * FROM polls WHERE pollid = 'test'";

Comment: Glad you've got it sorted - that's what changing `$pollid = $_GET['pollid'];` to `$pollid = "test";` would have done too though.